# Docker DNS Fully Qualified Domain Names

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns

I'm trying to use Docker's DNS to give my containers FQDN that they use to communicate with each other. I've use network aliases to do this, which partially works (they are resolved to the right IPs), but there is still a "default" hostname given to the services that is causing problems.

I have the following example docker compose file that shows the problem.

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  client1:
    container_name: client1
    image: openjdk:8-alpine
    command: [sh, -c, "nslookup app-two.domain.com && sleep 100"]
    hostname: app-one.domain.com
    domainname: domain.com
    networks:
      dns-network:
        aliases:
          - app-one.domain.com

  client2:
    container_name: client2
    image: openjdk:8-alpine
    command: [sh, -c, "nslookup app-one.domain.com && sleep 100"]
    hostname: app-two.domain.com
    domainname: domain.com
    networks:
      dns-network:
        aliases:
          - app-two.domain.com

networks:
  dns-network:
  name: dns-network
```

This produces output similar to the following:

```
client2    | Name:      app-one.domain.com
client2    | Address 1: 192.168.224.2 client1.dns-network
client1    | Name:      app-two.domain.com
client1    | Address 1: 192.168.224.3 client2.dns-network
```

Even though the proper FQDN (*.domain.com) is being resolved to the right container, there is still a reference to the "default" name (*.dns-network). Am I missing some configuration to achieve this, or is this simply not possible with Docker DNS? If it's not possible, what do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Why is it important to give your containers this alternate domain name?  Why is it important that reverse resolution not provide the Docker-standard names?

Comment: @DavidMaze the short answer is that the reverse resolution is causing problems with Kerberos & ZooKeeper as the service name is incorrect