# Get fully qualified MinIO S3-API URL from local MinIO container

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, docker-network, minio

I'm trying to access the Minio S3-API endpoint from within my container, but my app can't resolve the container name.

The issue is the framework that I'm [using](https://github.com/tus/tus-node-server/tree/main/packages/s3-store#new-s3storeoptions), uses the [@smithy/middleware-endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-smithy-middleware-endpoint/Interface/EndpointInputConfig/) API, which requires a fully qualified URL. As my MinIO instance is started with the rest of the stack with the endpoint passed into my app on start-up, using the container hostname; http://minio:9000 doesn't work.

However, I can't hardcode the IP in my docker-compose file as it changes every time I spin up docker-compose.

My docker-compose file looks something like this:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  backend:
    build: ./backend/tus/.
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8181:8181"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ENDPOINT=http://minio:9000
    depends_on:
      - minio

  # the minio instance that the back end streams the data uploads to
  minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=minioadmin
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minioadmin
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
```

The code that's using the environment variable `MINIO_ENDPOINT` looks something like this:

```
/* Set up the s3 store to pass to the tus server */
const datafileS3Store = new S3Store({
    s3ClientConfig: {
        bucket: process.env.DATAFILE_BUCKET,
        region: "eu-west-2",
        endpoint: process.env.MINIO_ENDPOINT,
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.MINIO_USERNAME,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.MINIO_PASSWORD,
        },
    },
})
```

However MinIO outputs its IP addresses on start-up, usually something like:

> S3-API: http://172.19.0.5:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000
>
> Console: http://172.19.0.5:9001 http://127.0.0.1:9001

So, does anyone know how I might be able to get (or even set?) the S3-API IP of the MinIO Instance and pass it into my backend container?

Comment: I think the issue is with `s3ClientConfig` resolving docker host names.

Comment: the docs for which are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-smithy-middleware-endpoint/Interface/EndpointInputConfig/

Comment: and that http://minio:9000 is not a fully "qualified" url

Comment: maybe there's a way of getting the minio s3-api IP address? or at least storing it to file to be read by the backend container.

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 2):

Your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77260261/6309) would be to create a custom network and assigned static IP addresses to the containers. That does allow for a predictable IP address for the MinIO container that can be hard-coded as an environment variable in the backend container.

```
+-----------------------------------+
|          Docker Host              |
|                                   |
| +-------------+  customnetwork    |
| |   Backend   |-----+             |
| | 172.20.0.11 |     |             |
| +-------------+     |             |
|                     |             |
| +-------------+     |             |
| |    MinIO    |-----+             |
| | 172.20.0.10 |                   |
| +-------------+                   |
|                                   |
| +-----------------+               |
| |  createbuckets  |               |
| |  172.20.0.13    |               |
| +-----------------+               |
|                                   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Each container is assigned a static IP address within the `customnetwork`. The Backend container can directly communicate with the MinIO container using the hard-coded IP address `172.20.0.10`.

---

But I would suggest using a BIND9 DNS container ([`sameersbn/docker-bind`](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-bind)), to declare and resolve a FQDN for minio.
See "[Running a DNS Server with Docker](https://mpolinowski.github.io/docs/DevOps/Provisioning/2022-01-25--installing-bind9-docker/2022-01-25/)" from [Mike Polinowski](https://mpolinowski.github.io/Personal/) for illustration.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                        Docker Host                          |
|                                                             |
|  +------------------+     +---------------------+           |
|  |      MinIO       |     |        BIND9        |           |
|  |   (Service 1)    |<--->|      (Service 2)    |           |
|  +------------------+     +---------------------+           |
|         |                   |                               |
|         | Interaction       | DNS Resolution                |
|         v                   v                               |
|  +-------------------+      minio.example.com               |
|  |   Backend/tus    |                                       |
|  |   (Service 3)    |                                       |
|  +-------------------+                                      |
|                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- MinIO service starts up first.
- BIND9 service starts, obtains MinIO's IP address, updates its zone file, and starts the DNS server.
- Other Docker containers or external clients can now resolve `minio.example.com` via the BIND9 DNS service, which resolves it to MinIO's IP address within the Docker network.

The docker-compose.yml ([v3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/)) would be:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:

  minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=minioadmin
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minioadmin
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"


  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc
    depends_on:
      - minio
      - bind9
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      /usr/bin/mc alias set minio http://minio.upload.com:9000 minioadmin minioadmin;
      /usr/bin/mc mb minio/datafiles;
      /usr/bin/mc policy set public minio/datafiles;
      exit 0;
      "


  bind9:
    image: sameersbn/bind
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - minio
    volumes:
      - ./dns_settings.sh:/scripts/dns_settings.sh
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        chmod +x ./scripts/dns_settings.sh 
        ./scripts/dns_settings.sh


volumes:
  minio_data:
```

The updated `docker-compose.yml` no longer mounts the `/bind` directory directly into `/etc/bind`, avoiding the overshadowing issue. Instead, it focuses on using a custom script for the BIND9 container to properly set up DNS records.

Instead of directly writing to `/etc/bind` within the `docker-compose.yml`, you can use a custom script named `setup-bind.sh` that will be executed by the BIND9 container on startup. That script will handle setting the IP variable correctly and configuring BIND:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
echo "The S3 client needs a FQDN which the docker network doesn't provide"
echo "getting minio address and creating a dns entry so we can use minio.upload.com as the FQDN"

echo "Perform nslookup to get MinIO IP address"
ip=$(nslookup minio | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 }')

echo "The IP address of the minio server is: $ip"

echo "create the BIND9 db.upload.com file"
cat > /etc/bind/db.upload.com <<EOF
\$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     minio.upload.com. admin.upload.com. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers - NS records
@      IN      NS      minio.upload.com.

; name servers - A records
minio.upload.com.          IN      A       $ip
EOF

echo "update named.conf.local to include the new zone"
echo "zone \"upload.com\" {
    type master;
    file \"/etc/bind/db.upload.com\";
};" >> /etc/bind/named.conf.local
echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
echo "start BIND9"
exec named -g
```

---

If `nslookup` is not available in the container, consider installing it if possible in your image.
And if health checks might be more appropriately configured in the `docker-compose.yml` file, you can use:

```yaml
services:
  minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. There's a syntax error on the bind9 entry point

Comment: also do we need the custom network at all now? As this docker-compose file has grown, I don't really want to add everything to a custom network.

Comment: @WhatTheWhat True, you can try without the custom network. And do not hesitate to edit the answer and fix the syntax error: I can then validate your edit.

Comment: thanks, I have updated the answer, however I'm getting:` /etc/bind/zones/db.example.com: No such file or directory`

Comment: `etc/bind` only contains: `bind.keys, db.127, db.empty, named.conf, named.conf.local, rndc.key, db.0, db.255, db.local, named.conf.default-zones, named.conf.options and zones.rfc1918`

Comment: @WhatTheWhat OK, I will check that after work.

Comment: I've been around the houses with this. The first issue was that the volume mount meant that bind couldn't see anything in the `/bind` folder. So I wrote the db.example file directly in `/etc/bind` but now the `nslookup` is not setting the IP variable.

Comment: the issue is with setting the variable $ip

Comment: ok i found the issue. It was with the command setting envs in its own parent context. It works when running it from a script (.sh) file

Comment: @WhatTheWhat Good catch. Can you edit the answer to include your findings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256868/discussion-between-vonc-and-whatthewhat).

Comment: Thanks for that. A couple of things: `ns` is not available in the container, the health checks should probably be done in the compose file. However, I'm not sure this answer works. Having successfully started bind, if I exec in to the container and do `nslookup minio.example.com` I get `server can't find minio.example.com: NXDOMAIN`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to create a new network and hardcode the container IP address so that the IP can be passed in as as an env var into the backend.

compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  backend:
    build: ./backend/tus/.
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8181:8181"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ENDPOINT=http://172.20.0.10:9000
      - MINIO_USERNAME=minioadmin
      - MINIO_PASSWORD=minioadmin
    depends_on:
      - minio
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.11


  # the minio instance that the back end streams the data uploads to
  minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=minioadmin
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minioadmin
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.10

  # script that inits minio with some buckets
  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc
    depends_on:
      - minio
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      /usr/bin/mc alias set minio http://172.20.0.10:9000 minioadmin minioadmin;
      /usr/bin/mc mb minio/datafiles;
      /usr/bin/mc policy set public minio/datafiles;
      exit 0;
      "
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.13

volumes:
  minio_data:

networks:
 customnetwork:
  ipam:
    config:
    - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

The key thing here is that all other containers need to be added to network:

```
networks:
  - customnetwork
```

Comment: Another alternative, but untested:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078085/docker-dns-fully-qualified-domain-names